# Distinct inside a CASE WHEN SQL

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
    SUM(NormalCount) NormalCount,
    SUM(DiscountCount) DiscountCount,
    SUM(TotalAmountNormal) TotalAmountNormal,
    SUM(TotalAmountDiscounted) TotalAmountDiscounted,
    COUNT(Trip_No) TotalTrip
  FROM
  (

  SELECT
    CASE WHEN PriceType_ID=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END NormalCount,
    CASE WHEN PriceType_ID<>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DiscountCount,
    CASE WHEN PriceType_ID=0 THEN Amount END TotalAmountNormal,
    CASE WHEN PriceType_ID<>0 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END TotalAmountDiscounted,
    DISTINCT(Trip_No) //here error

    FROM "Tbl_Ticket"
    WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datetime('now'), 'localtime') = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', Ticket_Date)
    AND Vehicle_ID=1
    AND Driver_ID=1
    AND Route_ID=93
    AND Ticket_Date BETWEEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', "2013-12-04 00:21:07") AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', "2013-12-04 00:50:50")
 ) t
```

i want to Distinct Trip_No and count how many the trip_no have, any idea?

Comment: What is your expected result: do you want 1) a single row that summarizes the entire table or 2) one row for each `trip_no`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Distinct` isn't a function, it's a keyword that can be used in a couple of ways. If can be used after `select` to tell the database to return only unique *rows* or it can be used within an aggregate function (i.e. `min`, `max`, `count`, etc.) to tell that function that it should be applied only to the set of unique values for *that field*. In the former case, it can be used in just about any query, but in the latter case (such as yours) the query must have a `group by` clause.

As had previously been suggested, it seems like the simplest solution for you case is to move the `distinct` keyword to within the `count` function:

```
SELECT
    SUM(NormalCount) NormalCount,
    SUM(DiscountCount) DiscountCount,
    SUM(TotalAmountNormal) TotalAmountNormal,
    SUM(TotalAmountDiscounted) TotalAmountDiscounted,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Trip_No) TotalTrip
  FROM( 
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN PriceType_ID=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END NormalCount,
      CASE WHEN PriceType_ID<>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DiscountCount,
      CASE WHEN PriceType_ID=0 THEN Amount END TotalAmountNormal,
      CASE WHEN PriceType_ID<>0 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END TotalAmountDiscounted,
      trip_no
    FROM "Tbl_Ticket"
    WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datetime('now'), 'localtime') = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', Ticket_Date)
      AND Vehicle_ID=1
      AND Driver_ID=1
      AND Route_ID=93
      AND Ticket_Date BETWEEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', "2013-12-04 00:21:07") AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', "2013-12-04 00:50:50")
  ) t
```

This solution will provide a single result row which will summarize the entire table. If you want one row per `trip_no`, @Gordon Linoff's answer is appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

I think the query you are looking for is an aggregation query:

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN PriceType_ID=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NormalCount,
       sum(CASE WHEN PriceType_ID<>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DiscountCount,
       sum(CASE WHEN PriceType_ID=0 THEN Amount END) as TotalAmountNormal,
       sum(CASE WHEN PriceType_ID<>0 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotalAmountDiscounted,
       Trip_No
FROM "Tbl_Ticket"
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datetime('now'), 'localtime') = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', Ticket_Date)
      AND Vehicle_ID=1
      AND Driver_ID=1
      AND Route_ID=93
      AND Ticket_Date BETWEEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', "2013-12-04 00:21:07") AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', "2013-12-04 00:50:50")
group by trip_no
```

Comment: It's not clear to me if the OP ultimately wants a single row or one row per `trip_no`. While this is a fine answer in the latter case, I think in this case that he would want the count of the number of trips returned as well (i.e. `count(*) as trip_cnt` or equivalent).

Comment: @Allan . . . I agree that the statement of what the OP wants is highly ambiguous and this is one interpretation.  It is also possible that s/he is just looking for `count(distinct trip_no)` in the outer select.